# I need to improve accessibility of my google sites inline with UK Legisltation

Tags: templates, navigation, accessibility

I need to improve the accessibility of my websites in line with UK Legislation. Google Lighthouse reports that the `aria-selected=”true”` attribute is invalid in the following snippet:

```
<a class="aJHbb dk90Ob jgXgSe HlqNPb" jsname="QwLHlb" role="link" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" href="/home" data-url="/home" data-type="1" title="Home" jsaction="keydown:mPuKz; click:vHQTA;" data-level="1">Home</a>
```

This error occurs across the site navigation for selected menu items. Please advise on a way to fix this issue within the template I am using for my site.”

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-selected) reports that the attribute `aria-selected` can be used with the following roles:

- gridcell
- option
- row
- tab

Your element has a role of link, which is not included in the list.

You can use `aria-current="page"` instead. [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-current) is the spec.